# Jquery parsing xml - find a attribute of a tag inside other tag

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

Still trying parsing
 [this xml:](http://henriquebarone.animatubo.com/spider/jquery/teste.xml)

I want to get the z_depth value of param tag with this code

```
$(sif).find('layer[type="import"] param[name="z_depth"] real').each(function(){
zdepth_value = $(this).attr('value');
    });
```

And print in css atribute with this code:

```
$('<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:'+zdepth_value+'"></div>').appendTo('#object');
```

But I don't get the attribute value

I put the code at :
[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVwpm/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no success with testing in jsfiddle, probably there is some restriction with testing ajax requests. But, this script work locally on my machine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var file_name = "http://henriquebarone.animatubo.com/spider/jquery/teste";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: file_name + ".xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: Parser
        });
    });

    function Parser(sif) {
        $(sif).find('layer[type="import"] param[name="z_depth"] real').each(function () {
            $('#object').append($('<span>' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span>'));
        });
    }
</script>
```